# Atiyah-Macdonald before proposition 4.9

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Atiyah-Macdonald's proposition 4.9 is preceded by the following statement.

> For any ideal $a$ and any multiplicatively closed subset $S$ in $A$, the contraction
> in $A$ of the ideal $S^{-1}a$ is denoted by $S(a)$.

I don't understand the meaning "$S(a)$".

If I consider $S(a)$ to be $\{sx\mid s\in S,x\in a\}$, then $S(a)$ becomes $a$. The notation seems odd.

Maybe I am not understanding correctly what contraction $(S^{-1}I)^c$ is.

How should this notation be considered? Please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right to say that $S(a)=(S^{-1}(a))^c$.
What is not true is that $(S^{-1}(a))^c=\{sx\mid s\in S,x\in a\}$.
The explicit expression of $(S^{-1}(a))^c$ is given in proposition 3.11, which states that $a^{ec}=\cup_{s\in S}(a:s)$. In general (as you can see also by the proposition you mention) the equality does not hold, i.e. $S(a)$ strictly contains $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I am reading the Japanese version of this book.

I also refer to the English version because some minor nuances have been lost in translation.

I believe the meaning of the sentence in the quoted passage is (i) below, and I was having trouble finding the definition of $S(a)$. Is the correct meaning (ii)?

(i) $(S^{-1}a)^c$ is equal to $S(a)$ already defined
(ii) $(S^{-1}a)^c$ is to be represented by a new symbol $S(a)$

Comment: @nat-cat It's (ii). In mathematical writing, "X is denoted by Y" means "we are introducing a new symbol Y which means X".

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did not read the statement correctly. I apologize for not understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Given a ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ and an ideal $I\subseteq B$, the contraction of $I$ (along $f$) is the preimage $f^{-1}(I)$, which is an ideal in $A$.

The definition of $S(\mathfrak{a})$ is the contraction of the ideal $S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}$ (along the canonical ring homomorphism $A\to S^{-1}A$).

Unpacking the definitions, we find that $x\in S(\mathfrak{a})$ if and only if $\frac{x}{1}=\frac{a}{s}$ for some $a\in \mathfrak{a}$ and $s\in S$. Equivalently, $x\in S(\mathfrak{a})$ if and only if there exists $s\in S$ such that $sx\in\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I now understand the correct meaning.